# How can I influence the address of a function?

Tags: c, assembly

is there a method to influence, set or define the (relative) address of a function? Maybe there are any possibilities witin the linker script to make sure function abc() always resides at OFFSET+0x0034C0 (just an example).
I want to somehow "control" the location of functions inside the memory to make those locations some kind of parametrized.
At the moment I am looking for an approach on my x86 using gcc. However, the real application should run on an embedded device.

Regards

Comment: IMO, If the application runs on a embedded device with, I assume, a custom OS of some sort, do not try to make it work on a x86 and then find out it cannot be done on the device.
(curious, why?)

Comment: Have you looked at storing pointers to functions inside of a data structure?

Comment: This sounds very much like an XY question, you are trying to solve problem X, so you THINK the solution involved Y, so you ask for how to do Y. Can you please explain a little further what you are actually trying to do? I would think using function pointers or something similar is a very likely candidate, but without actually understanding the real thought behind "I need my function on a special address", it's hard to know what solution to suggest.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: You are right indeed. My goal is to create a hardware-software-binding-scheme. More details can be found in my comment to unwind's answer.

Comment: So, it sounds more like "I want a block of code to be accessible only if some authentication is successful", which I would solve by either:
1. Placing the whole block in a section [see how __init is defined in Linux, for example], and then only map that region into virtual space from your MMU if the authentication worked. 
2. Use function pointers as described before, and either use a different set of pointers, or set the pointers to a function that stops [or does some other "This doesn't work" action] if the authentication failed.

Comment: Access the function table via a software interrupt, (and maybe function table index passed as first parameter)?

Answer (score 8):

You can probably do it using [linker script magic](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/ld_3.html#SEC4) with gcc, yes. Look at how to define [section placement](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/ld_3.html#SEC16), then put directives in your source to put functions in the section(s) of your choice.

Not at all sure if that will work in the x86 machine though, since the operating system might have ... objections. This is more for embedded use directly.

What would be the *point* of controlling code location on a full operating system?

Comment: Actually I want to create some Software-Hardware-Binding-Scheme. The location of certain functions shall be defined during the development of the software. While executing the software it reads authentification information from the hardware which is used to direct the control flow of the software.
Only if the right credentials were read from the hardware, successive functions calls point to the right memory addresses. Else they point to wrong locations in memory and the execution of software stops / the software crashes.

Comment: @user1192748, I've seen a similar result by just storing a checksum of the contents of particular hardware addresses (such as the interrupt vector).

Comment: @user1192748 The CRC check has the advantage that you can simply check the value and not run if it doesn't match.  Invoking undefined behavior is just a recipe for disaster (i.e. you can't control when/where/how the software "stops", if it "stops")

Comment: yes, with the gnu linker you can control the location of an object, and by arranging the functions in the source file you can control what function is first and/or have only one function per object.  (it is not all that magical)

Comment: @JoshPetitt could you provide additional references to the checksum approach?

Comment: look at http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10237.pdf Chapter 30 section 5.1.1

Answer (score 1):

A typical generalized implementation to this would be a vector table (I've also heard this called a patch table).

First, in your C file, write your functions:

```
void my_first_function(int){ /* do something */ }
void my_second_function(int){ /* do something */ }
```

Then, in your C file create a structure that defines the layout of the table:

```
struct MyVectorTable
{
  void (*first_function)(int);
  int (*second_function)(float, char);

  // all the rest
};
```

Next, in your C file create a static table:

```
static struct MyVectorTable my_vector_table = {
  my_first_function,
  my_second_function,
};
```

Finally expose the address as a void*

```
void* get_table_base_address(void) { return &my_vector_table; }
```

Now you should be able to get to all the functions as an offset from the base address.

If all your functions have the same call signature you can simplify this by having an array of function pointers instead of the struct.  However, both the array and the struct will hold pointers, so the pointer math is basically the same.

This also allows you to locate your patch table at a specific address using the linker.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this, IMO, is to place functions into user-defined sections as *unwind* has mentioned above. You can find a simple example that places a function `myFunc` at a 4kByte boundary below:

Create a new section in your memory by modifying the Linker Script:

```
/* .my_section will be the name of the section in the final executable */
.my_section : ALIGN (8)
{
    . = ALIGN (0x1000);

    KEEP(*(.mysection))    /* The section will be called ".mysection" in the
                              compiled translation unit (.obj) */

    . = ALIGN (8);
} >rom
```

Now, use gcc's `attribute` feature to place the function into the section we just created:

```
void myFunc(void) __attribute__ ((section(".mysection"))); // The section name to use 
                                                           // here is ".mysection", 
                                                           // not ".my_section"

// Looks like you need to use __attribute__ along with function declaration, rather 
// than with the function definition, though I'm not sure why

void myFunc(void)
{
    // ...
}
```

If you do `objdump` now, you'll see a section by the name `.my_section` holding the code of `myFunc` at address `0x2000`, rather than at `0x12e8`

```
Disassembly of section .my_section:

000012e8 <myFunc-0xd18>:
        ...

00002000 <myFunc>:
    2000:       b508            push    {r3, lr}
    ...
```

This code works with `Codesourcey gcc` suite for ARM-Cortex. I'm not quite sure about x86...